# Arduino SPI Daisy Chaining

Tags: arduino, spi

I want to operate a large set of servos in conjunction with various sensors, each module controlled by an Arduino nano. In order to send overhead operational data to the nanos, I want to use an Arduino mega with SPI communication, daisy chaining the master mega to the nano slaves.

The problem is I don't have any EE/CS background, and I'm not sure where to begin in terms of programming the communication. In terms of hardware limitation for SPI, I'm aware of the distance catch, but all the modules are within a meter from the mega.

I want to send two bytes of data to each module, and receive one byte of data back. For a size of **n** modules, I was thinking I need to pass an array with a size of 3 * **n**, with slave reading the data and then after storing, sending it out to the next one.

I've been trying to find specific codes to see how the communication is used, but I could not find any.
I did find https://github.com/hideakitai/SPIDaisyChain but thought that the slave and master would require separate files?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Implementing SPI slaves on a nano is a challenge - as soon as the master shifts another byte, you have to be ready to read it. The nano has no buffer on its spi peripheral. The faster the spi rate, the more problems you will encounter. That's not to say it can't be done, but it will be challenging. There's also the challenge of the wiring to ensure you don't get crosstalk etc. There's I2C (TWI) it too has its challenges, but it would be easier than SPI methinks. Personally I'd be looking at RS485 and running a multidrop network.

Comment: @Kartman as long as the clock rate is turned down, there shouldn't be too big of a problem right? I2C had a hardware limitation of 128, and I need (almost) simultaneous control of the modules, which is why I opted for SPI. Does nano's specs not have the ability to consistently catch incoming data?